# How to set the edge length for STL export?

Tags: export

I am trying to reduce the size of a very large STL file, that as of now includes way too much detail. In Blender is there an option to set the minimum and maximum edge length of the exported STL file, so that I could just set a larger minimum edge length than the current one?

If this option does not work is there another option that allows me to easily remove detail from an STL file or smooth surfaces of a geometry? I attached a cutout of the geometry. I am only interested in the macroscopic geometry not in the surface texture.

[image: Cutout of the imported geometry]

Comment: Something [like this](https://www.blendernation.com/2018/06/14/instant-meshes-remeshing-add-on/)? The [remesh modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html) is another option.

Comment: Hi sambler, thanks for your comment! Right now my PC is working hard in my attempt to use the Decimate Modifier. If after lunch this was not successful I will look into your suggestions.

Comment: Hi @sambler right now I am still waiting for feedback from Blender after entering a `0.1` in the `Collapse` option of the `Decimate` modifier. Unfortunately it also looks like the modifier is not working in parallel, but only running on one thread. I can't tell if the calculation will take another hour, another day or another week.